# What does the warning «Use properties from the build variant packages» mean?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

What does this warning mean?

It is appeared in version 1.0.0-beta-3595 for all usages of kotlin android extensions in my code.

[image: Kotlin warning «Use properties from the build variant packages»]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think they did this to support multiple build variants. For example when you have a flavour `proversion` and you want to use a layout from that flavour you have to use

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.proversion.activity_main.*
```

For the `main` build variant you have to use

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly the answer to the question 'why did they do that', but that's how to eliminate warning.
Change

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.activity_main.*
```

to

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

implying that you already bumped version in `build.gradle` and updated IDEA (or AS) kotlin plugins.